# Is it possible to recover from a panic inside a panic?

Tags: go

It looks like it's not possible to recover from a panic inside a panic?

```
func TestError(t *testing.T) {

    e := &myErr{p: false}
    fmt.Println(e.Error())  // this prints "returned"
    panic(e)                // this prints "panic: returned"

    e1 := &myErr{p: true}
    fmt.Println(e1.Error()) // this prints "recovered"
    panic(e1)               // this prints "panic: panic: paniced
                            //              fatal error: panic holding locks 
                            //              panic during panic"
}

type myErr struct {
    p bool
}

func (m *myErr) Error() (out string) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            out = "recovered"
        }
    }()
    if m.p {
        panic("paniced")
    }
    return "returned"
}
```

Backstory: My error Error() function uses os.Getwd, which seems to always panic when inside a panic, so I'd like to handle this gracefully.

Comment: Why are you panicking in the first place? Are you trying to use panics as an exception mechanism? As you can see, you shouldn't do anything that might also panic while trying to recover.

Comment: I'm definitely not over using panics. In my usage a panic will only ever occur due to programmer error, not user error.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what the "testing" package is doing different right now. It would be useful to try and figure out how to replicate this as a standalone example, to see if it's a bug or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it solves your problem to replace this

```
panic(e1)
```

by this

```
panic(e1.Error())
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/fXpX2ch9eF

And the question here is interesting: why? This is the hard part and I don't know the exact answer. Probably the problem here is that we panicing after all deffered functions executed (so when Go does try to print the panic error string). Any correction is welcomed if it's not correct!

Comment: Yes that's the work-around I settled on, but I'd love a more complete explanation of why it doesn't work...